# Change post status if SKU doesn't exists [WP All Import + Woocommerce]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

Is there way to change post status if SKU doesn't exists when comparing CSV and existing products?

ie. If I have product with SKU 12345 and that SKU doesn't exists in CSV file, change post status to "Draft". If it does exists in CSV file, change post status to "Published"

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

You can update post status to `publish` for items that do exist in the CSV with something like this (code not tested, goes into `functions.php` of your [child] theme):

```
function my_check_post_status ($continue_import, $post_id, $data, $import_id ) {

    // Only process import ID 1, change this to match your import ID:
    if ($import_id == 1) {

        // Change 'sku' to the column name that contains your SKU.
        $sku = $data['sku'];

        // Check if the SKU already exists.
        $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

        if ( $product_id ) {

            // If product ID exists then set status to Published
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID'    =>  $product_id,
                'post_status'   =>  'publish'
                ));
        }
    } else {
        // Do nothing if it's not our specified import ID.
        return $continue_import;
    }
}

add_filter( 'wp_all_import_is_post_to_update', 'my_check_post_status', 10, 4 );
```

For products that **do not** exist in the CSV there's no easy way to detect during import.

One thing you can do is run custom code *before* the import which sets *all* posts to `draft`, then run the import which will update the ones that exist in the CSV to `publish`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this and your advice. I think that could be the easiest way to do that. Could there be other solution outside WP All Import what would do comparison? Custom function with looping each product and compare to CSV file?

Comment: You can write custom code to do that - or have someone write it for you. It would either be close to what I describe, or some type of WordPress plugin that consumes your CSV file and goes through its SKUs to update the existing products.